# Segmentation error and struct variables fail to print to file

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm receiving a segmentation fault when I try to print some variables in a struct to file. When I first wrote the code, I was able to print the result onto the screen just fine with the exception of a segmentation fault that shows up at the very end

However, when I changed my code so that I am printing to file, it creates the file, but the file is empty and a `segmentation fault` prints to screen instead.

Any advice?

```
/* all is an array of struct CASE, 
   artall is an array of struct ARTCOUNT, 
   pLast is last element in all */

void printArtCount (CASE* all, ARTCOUNT* artAll, CASE* pLast)
{
  ARTCOUNT* artWalker = artAll;
  CASE* walker;
  char input[51];
  FILE* spOut;

  printf("File name for artist count output: ");
  scanf("%50s", input);
  spOut = fopen(input, "w");

  while(artWalker->name)
  {
    fprintf(spOut, "%d ", artWalker->count);
    fprintf(spOut, "%s\n", artWalker->name);
    for(walker = all; walker <= pLast; walker++)
    {
       if (strcmp(walker->name, artWalker->name) == 0)
         fputs(walker->art, spOut);
    }
   artWalker++;
  } 

 return;
}
```

Edit: Fixed the code so that segmentation error no longer shows up.
EVerything works now.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you expect that `while` loop to work? Do you know what happens if you dereference a pointer to uninitialized memory? Have you heard of "undefined behavior"?

Comment: @cnicutar: `artWalker` is a pointer, and you're going to increment it until it's null?

Comment: @Beta Yup, that's right. I suspect the OP meant `while(*artWalker)`.

Comment: @cnicutar what happens when `artWalker++` gets executed? Are we sure that we are operating on an array?!

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj Well, are you sure the OP isn't operating on an array ? `artWalker++` could very well be valid.

Comment: Yes, that was my plan. Should I be using a forloop instead?

Comment: @hyngyn what is `artAll`? is it an array or a linked-list?

Comment: @SangeethSaravanaraj Sorry for the important detail; both artAll and all are arrays of structs. Made the change to the code.

Comment: How do you expect the loop to end? Did you mean `while(*artWalker)`? Did you write code for converting an `ARTCOUNTER` to a bool? Did you verify that you can construct an `ARTCOUNTER` that evaluates to FALSE? Did you terminate the array with such an `ARTCOUNTER`? Even if you can get such juggling to work, it's much better to pass the length of the array as an argument, along with a pointer to the head, and use a `for` loop. And there are better methods once you're familiar with that one.

Comment: @Beta You were right, I had to change it to while(artWalker->name) for the loop to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be reading the array out of its limit.

Please try the following way of looping through the array elements.

```
len = sizeof(artWalker)/sizeof(artWalker[0]);

for (i=0; i<len ; i++) {
    ...
    artWalker[i]->struct_member;
    ...
}
```

Comment: nope, artWalker is a pointer, not an array. your sizeof division doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've figured out what the problem was; had to make sure that I'm checking that walker->name is not null instead of just walker.